# Sonata admin - 2 admins in one

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Is it possible to display the form of an admin in/next to the form of another admin?

```
$formMapper
            ->add('color', null, array('label' => 'label.color'))
            ->add('coverButtons', 'sonata_type_collection', array(), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
            ));
```

Right now, it's displaying a button which opens a pop-up with the other admin form but I would like to display the other admin form on the same page. Are there any configrations that might do this?

Comment: just make a parent form and use a [collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `sonata_type_admin`, example :

```
$formMapper->add('coverButtons', 'sonata_type_admin', array(), array(
    'edit'       => 'inline',
    'inline'     => 'table',
    'admin_code' => 'sonata.admin.your_admin_service_name',
));
```

This will embed the form of the `admin_code` inside your parent form.

See [the form field chapter of SonataAdmin documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-admin)